# vb.net dt.select not recognizing data changed in dgv

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dt

I populate a dt using an sql query.
It gets 3 rows

```
pn tag 
p1 52 
RT 78 
RT 99
```

if I run the following select, I will get 2

```
(dt.select("pn='rt'")).count 'returns 2
```

I use the dt as the datasource for a dgv, where I change the second row to have a pn of p1.

```
pn tag
p1 52
p1 78
RT 99
```

I can show the new data in a messagebox no prob

```
messagebox.show(dt.rows(1)("pn")) 'returns p1
```

But when I rerun the above select, I still get 2.  And if I run it for p1 I still get 1.

```
(dt.select("pn='rt'")).count 'still returns 2
(dt.select("pn='p1'")).count 'still returns 1
```

I can even do a select on the tag# and it return the correct (changed) p/n!

```
messagebox.show((dt.select("tag=78"))(0)("pn").tostring) 'returns p1
```

It's like the .select only *searches* on the 'original' copy of the dt instead of the current data, even though it returns current.
What am I missing?

**Solution:**
When I was done editing a field, I was automatically clicking (ot TABing) in another field of the same row.
If you either click in a different row, or, I added a focus elsewhere at the start of the *CellValueChanged* event, the .select suddenly uses the updated data in its search

```
other_DGV.Focus()
```

Comment: The `Count` method you're calling has got nothing at all to do with the `DataTable`. `Select` returns an array and then you're calling the `Enumerable.Count` extension method on that. It's simply impossible that that method could count something that the `Select` method is not returning. What you describe would be magic. The only way I can see that you could get the results you describe is if you were getting the count before the changes had been committed, i.e. before navigating to another row in the grid. The fact that all your code is in lower case suggests that it's not your actual code.

Comment: I tested what you describe and, as expected, I do not see the same behaviour. I populated a `DataTable` with the data you describe and bound it to a `DataGridView`. I then used a `Button` to write the record counts based on the `pn` column to the console. I clicked the `Button` before editing the data and the counts wree exactly as expected. I then edited the second record and clicked the `Button` again and the counts had changed exactly as expected. Either something on your system is broken or you're not telling us the whole story.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Also, you should not be using message boxes for debugging. Learn how to debug properly, using breakpoints and the Autos, Locals, Watch and Immediate windows. If you debug properly then you may well be able to spot what you're doing wrong because you'll be able to see the sequence in which different parts of the code are executed and what the state is at every step.